# Is variable called "name" always defined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
document.writeln('name=' + name); 
// name =

document.writeln('notName=' + notName); 
// ReferenceError: notName is not defined
```

Does the "name" have some special meaning in javascript? (checked in IE and FF)

Comment: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Comment: +1 for testing this right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is variable called “name” always defined in Javascript?

No. However, *on browsers* there's a global called `name` which is the name of the current window. This is a by-product of the fact that the JavaScript global object on browsers is the Window object. A bit of explanation:

In JavaScript, global variables are actually *properties* of something called the "global object." On browsers, the global object is the Window object for the page, and so it has all kinds of predefined properties (and therefore globals) on it related to it being a [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), including but not limited to:

- `name` - The name of the current window
- `title` - The title of the current window
- `status` - The status area content (except most browsers ignore it)
- `document` - The document in the current window
- `window` - A reference back to the global object (e.g., a circular reference)
- `setTimeout` - A function used for scheduling something to happen later

...and many others. It also gets all kinds of other things thrown into it, such as a property for every DOM element that has an `id` (the property's name is the `id`, its value is a reference to the DOM element), on some browsers the same is true for DOM elements with a `name` property, and so on. It's very cluttered.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `window.name` can be used for storage (it's ancient method) and it's possible to keep there from 30 to 60MB. Source: http://michalbe.blogspot.com/2013/03/javascript-less-known-parts-storage.html

Answer (score 4):

`name` is a property of `window`

`notName` is not, until it is defined as such

```js
var output = "window.name: " + window.name + "\r\n" + "name: " + name;
alert(output);
```