# How to store value of an array from prompt in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a simple program in Javascript which will take 10 inputs from user and stored in an array and then display the input in console.

Below the code which I have already write:

```
var name = [];
for(var i =0; i<=10; i++){
    name[i]=(prompt('Enter your name'));
}
console.log(name);
```

But it is not showing any values and I have tried to console values of i inside the for loop. 
It is showing undefined in console. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: That should work (although using `prompt` is not ideal). *Edit: Ah, no, because you've used `name`, probably at global scope in a browser...*

Comment: Side note: 0 to 10 inclusive (e.g., starting with 0 and going `<= 10`) is **eleven** times, not ten.

Comment: Do I need to change the variable scope or name of the variable?

Comment: Amir I have tried this. It is not working also.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562719/is-variable-called-name-always-defined-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be running that code at global scope in a browser. `name` is already defined in the global namespace on browsers. It's the name of the current window (a string). You can't shadow it in global scope via `var`, you have to use a scoping function or similar:

```
(function() {
    var name = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {           // Note 1
        name[i] = prompt('Enter your name'); // Note 2
    }
    console.log(name);
})();
```

The lesson here: Avoid global scope. :-)

Note 1: You want `< 10`, not `<= 10`, if you only want 10 loops.

Note 2: You don't need to put `()` around the entire right-hand side of an assignment.

Comment: _You can't shadow it in global scope via var_ But I could overlap it when I execute `var name = 1000;`, At the same time, I couldn't when I execute `var name = [];`. Can you explain it why?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Because `name` is a string and its type cannot be changed. Assigning `1000` to it results in it being `"1000"` (the string), as though you'd assigned `String(1000)`. Assigning an empty array to it is like you assigned `String([])`, which is `[].toString()`, which is `[].join()`, which is `[].join(",")`, which is `""`.

Comment: Totally understand. _Because name is a string and its type cannot be changed._ Is it so? Can't we change a type of a default property in window?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: It depends entirely on the property. `name`? No. Remember that `window` is a host-provided object. Host-provided objects can have non-JavaScript behavior (like fixed types).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot for your info. I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects) too, to get a clear understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code :

```
var nm = new Array(10);
for(var i =0; i<10; i++){
    nm[i]=prompt('Enter your name'); 
}
for(var i =0; i<10; i++){
   document.write(nm[i] + '<br>');
}
```

We can't use variable name as 'name'. As well to get array value we have to provide index number in array, so in above using for loop to get all values.

Thanks...