# Trying To Split Array Element By Space

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am confused why this code results with name[0] being equal to "f" instead of "foo". I thought that when I passed ' ' to the split method "foo" would be the result.

```js
var ar = [];
ar[0] = "foo bar";
ar[1] = "dumdumdum";

var name = ar[0].split(' ');
console.log(name[0]);
```

Comment: Try it with a variable name other than `name`. Or put the code inside a function so that `name` is a local variable. There is a built-in global `window.name` property that is always a string, and your `name` is referencing that property, hence your array gets converted to a string and then `name[0]` gets the first character of that string. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562719/is-variable-called-name-always-defined-in-javascript).

Comment: "***In browsers** there is a global window.name property…*". ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The variable `name` is reserved in browsers. If you were to go in the developer console *(click f12)*, and type `window.name`, you would see that it either gives you `""` or some other string result.
- Your previous code `ar[0].split(' ');` is going to return the following array:

  ```
  [
     "foo",
     "bar"
  ]
  ```
- but the browser forcibly converts it to a string *because your browser is mad at you since you are trying to change the `typeof` of its reserved variable* **;)**, hence the string value `"foo,bar"`. You might however get different results on different browsers.
- And doing `name[0]` to a string value of `"foo,bar"` gets the first letter of the string, `f`

Comment: @nnnnnn name refers to window.name which is reserved and must be a string

Comment: @anonman - I know - I was the first to say so above. I was trying to prompt Webeng to update the answer...

Comment: @nnnnnn Okay. The answer doesn't explain that.

Answer (score 4):

"name" refers to window.name and is in use.
 so your array becomes a string.

Use another variable such as array2

```
var ar = [];
ar[0] = "foo bar";
ar[1] = "dumdumdum";

var name2 = ar[0].split(' ');
console.log(name2[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using the `name` as a variable, as this is an existing JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods. Your code should work after you rename the variable `name` to anything else, check the code belopw.

Your `var name = ar[0].split(' ');` returns an array of substrings.

```js
var ar = [];
ar[0] = "foo bar";
ar[1] = "dumdumdum";

var changeThisVariableName = ar[0].split(' ');  
console.log(changeThisVariableName[0]);
```

Comment: *"Your var name = ar[0].split(' '); return a string"* - But...`.split()` always returns an array.

Comment: @nnnnnn I thought it returns an array of substrings. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It *does* return an array of substrings. But what you said in your answer in the bit that I quoted is that it returns a string. Regarding your edit, that wording still doesn't make sense, because you can't `.split()` an array. Bottom line is that the issue here has nothing to do with `.split()`, it's about whether you can have a global variable called `name`...

Comment: @nnnnnn I see what you're saying. I think, OP's problem is that `name` variable is reserved? Because if you rename that variable to anything else, that code should work.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a function, you will get exactly result because name refer to window.name

```
(function () {
    var ar = [];
    ar[0] = "foo bar";
    ar[1] = "dumdumdum";

    var name = ar[0].split(' ');
    console.log(name[0]);
})()
```

Comment: This is not a very good workaround, and will bite you for seemingly unknown reasons if you move the code outside a function.