# Declaring javascript arrays with/without jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm declaring this array in a javascript script:

```
    var status=[
    {
        "name":"name1",
        "level":0
    },
    {
        "name":"name2",
        "level":0
    },
    {
        "name":"name3",
        "level":0
    },
    {
        "name":"name4",
        "level":0
    },
    {
        "name":"name5",
        "level":0
    }];
console.log(status);
```

If i declare it inside the

```
$('document').ready(function(){
});
```

function, then the console.log(status) return me an array of objects (like I want it to be).

But if I declare it outside the document ready function, it will return this string:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

And, i repeat, it's a string...

Maybe it is something stupid but I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562719/is-variable-called-name-always-defined-in-javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is a pre-existing global whose value you can't set to an array (it can only be a string, in theory it's the status text shown in the browser's footer, if it has one; and browsers ignore it these days):

```js
console.log("before:", typeof status);
var status = [];
console.log("after:", typeof status);
```

If you set it to a non-string, either the browser will ignore it, or (as in your case) it will coerce to string — what you're seeing is what you get for an array with plain objects in it when you coerce to string:

```js
console.log(String([{}, {}, {}]));
```

This is one of the reasons not to use globals, on browsers the global namespace is really crowded. Instead, wrap your code in a scoping function (whether you use `ready` or just an IIFE). Or if you **have** to have a global, have just **one** (like jQuery [almost] does), and make it an object with properties on for the various things you want to be "global".

Comment: For this reason, I frequently add an underscore for any global I need to create, and also usually add my application name. Ex: `__appnameStatus`

Comment: Does OP say `status` is pre-existing global?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: OP says their code doesn't work at global scope. The above is why.