# Unable to appendChild data from a promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm having problems when appending to the body the data returned by a promise. I console log it and everything seem to be working fine, however, when I try to do a simple appendChild to the body, I receive an error which says: "functions.js:73 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'"
I looked this error up on the internet, here in StackOverflow and someone has already asked the same question, but the answer he got doesn't work for me.

Please, can you take a look and help me figure out what's wrong here?

Thanks.

```
fetchUsers()
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(json => {
    listUsers(json);
    return fetchJanet();
  })
  .then(janetData => janetData.json())
  .then(janet => listJanet(janet.data));

function fetchUsers() {
  return fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users");
}

function listUsers(json) {
  users = json.data;
  users.forEach((element, i) => {
    n = document.createElement("h3");
    n.innerHTML =
      element.first_name + " " + element.last_name + " have an index of: " + i;
    document.body.appendChild(n);
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
  });
}

function fetchJanet() {
  return fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
}

function listJanet(element) {
  console.log(element);
  name = document.createElement("p");
  name.innerHTML = element.first_name + " " + element.last_name;
  document.body.appendChild(name);
}
```

Comment: change `name = document.createElement("p");` to `var name = document.createElement("p");` - because the **global** `name` will mess you up all the time

Comment: I would also change `users = json.data;` to `var users = json.data;` and `n = document.createElement("h3");` to `var n = document.createElement("h3");` etc etc ... **avoid globals**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562719/is-variable-called-name-always-defined-in-javascript for an explanation about the global `name`

Comment: i.e. always declare variables using `var`, `let` or `const` unless you really do want to access a variable in an outer scope

Comment: Guys are right. And suggestion: try to use better names... `response` instead of `json`, `header` instead of `n` and so on. This will really make the world a better place :)